# Issue with dynamically adding textview android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, textview

I have a expandable listview which contains a submit button. On click of submit button text view should be created one before the previous one. I tried with the below code .. but  it not displaying correctly. Two textviews are added correctly but thereafter it replacing the old textviews..Please tell me what wrong with my code

```
   imGbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
            public void onClick(View v) {
    int prevTextViewId = 0;
    int curTextViewId = prevTextViewId + 1;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    final TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
    textView.setText(data);     
    textView.setId(curTextViewId);
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView.getId());
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    tvll.addView(textView, params);
    }
    });
```

Comment: i think linearlayout will help you instead of relative

Comment: Consider not to add element dynamically, but to have it in you layout markup, just hidden by default. Then, in your click handler you can find the hidden element, fill it's text and set `visibility` to `visible`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set the view to be below itself with this:

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView.getId());
```

I think you want it to be this: (assuming you want it to be above, as you say in your question)

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, prevTextViewId);
```

You also need to track your prevTextViewId outside of this method.  Make it part of your class.

```
int prevTextViewid = 0; //part of your class
   ...

   imGbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
       public void onClick(View v) {
       int curTextViewId = prevTextViewId + 1;
       Random rnd = new Random();
       TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
       textView.setText(data);     
       textView.setId(curTextViewId);
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
          new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, prevTextViewId );
       textView.setLayoutParams(params);
       tvll.addView(textView, params);
       prevTextViewId = curTextViewId;
   }
});
```

Comment: hmm tried your suggestion ..but nothing on my way :( overwriting the existing..is that problem with the   prevTextViewId ( initialization/increment)

Answer (score 0):

By looking your tvll, It seems that you have taken linear layout for textview, so
Try with this-

```
imGbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
        public void onClick(View v) {
  int prevTextViewId = 0;
  int curTextViewId = prevTextViewId + 1;
  Random rnd = new Random();
  final TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
  textView.setText(data);     
  textView.setId(curTextViewId);
  final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  textView.setLayoutParams(params);
  tvll.addView(textView, params);
}
});
```

Comment: What have you taken LL or RL?

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void addTextView() {
    int prevId = 1;
    for (int m = 1; m <= 3; m++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("TextView  : " + m);
        textView.setId(m);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, prevId);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        relative.addView(textView);
        prevId = m;
    }
}
```

m adding thm in loop ...u can implement with ur own way... this is using relative layout only...